# Interface constraints in generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Let's say, I have a list of **strategies** which are presented as interfaces and a class (**Container**) which implements these strategies explicitly. Now I want a method to perform one of these strategies as it's specified in the generic type parameter. The question is in the code.

```
interface IStrategy
{
     void PerformAction();
}

interface IChasingStrategy : IStrategy
{
     new void PerformAction();
}

interface ITestStrategy : IStrategy
{
     new void PerformAction();
}

class Container : IChasingStrategy, ITestStrategy
{

     void IChasingStrategy.PerformAction()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("ChasingStrategy");
     }

     void IStrategy.PerformAction()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Strategy");
     }

     void ITestStrategy.PerformAction()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("TestStrategy");
     }
}

class Program
{
      static void PerformStrategy<TStrategy>(Container container) where TStrategy : IStrategy
      {
          TStrategy strategy = container; //why can't I use here implicit casting?
                                          //However this is valid:
                                          //IStrategy strat = container;
                                          //IChasingStrategy ch_strat = container;
                                          //ITestStrategy ts_strat = container;
          strategy.PerformAction();
      }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          var container = new Container();
          PerformStrategy<IChasingStrategy>(container);
      }
}
```

Comment: Why not change it to `PerformStrategy<TStrategy>(TStrategy strategy)`? And you'd still be able to pass a `Container` to `PerformStrategy<IChasingStrategy>`

Comment: Because `class AnotherStrategy:IStrategy` `PerformStrategy<AnotherStrategy>(...)`.

Comment: You can use `TStrategy container` instead of `Container container`, like `PerformStrategy<TStrategy>(TStrategy container) where TStrategy : IStrategy`

Comment: @Pavel Anikhouski, if i call PerformStrategy<IChasingContainer>(container) i will get IStrategy.PerformAction() implementation which is not what i expect. I expect IChasingStrategy.PerformAction() to be called

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say that the question is "in the code", but the only question I see there is _"why can't I use here implicit casting?"_. Are you really asking just that? If so, the answer is trivially obvious: you have no idea what `TStrategy` is at compile time, and the fact that it implements `IStrategy` in no way guarantees that it's assignable from a `Container` value. If you're asking something else, then...what? There's no other question in your post. What _are_ you asking?

Comment: It looks to me like a fundamental cause of your dilemma is the fact that you've chosen to use hiding (i.e. `new`) instead of overriding for the duplicate members in your interfaces. Frankly, I have never run into a situation where hiding a base type member made things better, and almost always it makes things worse. IMHO, avoid member hiding at all costs. You should take a different approach, and let polymorphism work in your favor instead of you having to work around a fundamental design flaw in your type hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and advice, I will try to come up with a different approach

Answer (score 0):

You can let it decide at runtume, which Strategy should it run by the following code.

```
class Container<T> Where T : IStrategy
{
        public void ActionFactory()
        {
                T.PerformAction();
        }
        .
        .
        .
}
```

And in the Program class:

```
static void PerformStrategy<TStrategy>(Container<TStrategy> container) where TStrategy : IStrategy
{
        container.ActionFactory(); //to perform the desired action for your strategy
}
```

When you calling the PerformStrategy method, you can decide what container should it get by:

```
PerformStrategy(new Container<IChasingStrategy>);
```

You can take off the class binding by making the ActionFactory method generic.

```
class Container
{
        public void ActionFactory<T>() where T: IStrategy
        {
                T.PerformAction();
        }
        .
        .
        .
}
class Program
{
        static void PerformStrategy<TStrategy>(Container container) where T: IStrategy
        {
                container.ActionFactory<TStrategy>(); //to perform the desired action for your strategy
        }
}

PerformStrategy<IChasingStrategy>(new Container());
```

Comment: I do not understand this line:
T.PerformAction();